# How to read data from a csv file using API in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, api

I am trying to download data from the following link:
[NHTSA Website](https://webapi.nhtsa.gov/Default.aspx?SafetyRatings/API/5)

If I create the link as below, it downloads the CSV file on my machine
http://webapi.nhtsa.gov/api/SafetyRatings/modelyear/2019/make/ACURA/model/RDX?format=csv

How can I read this file for different vehicles, using API in Python?

Here is my code so far:

```
db = sql.connect("localhost","root","password","TEST")

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM TEST.car_model"
cursor.execute(sql)

data = cursor.fetchall()

for row in data:
    apiUrl = "http://webapi.nhtsa.gov/api/SafetyRatings/modelyear/"
    apiParams = str(row[1])+"/make/"+row[2].replace(" ","%20")+"/model/"+row[3].rstrip().replace(" ","%20")
    apiFormat = "?format=csv"
    link = apiUrl + apiParams + apiFormat
    response = urlopen(apiUrl + apiParams + apiFormat)

    f = open(link, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

db.close()
```

Will response automatically download the file into my Downloads folder?

Comment: what code have you written?

Comment: Added code in OP

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
model = input("Enter model name: ")
year = input("year: ")

url = "http://webapi.nhtsa.gov/api/SafetyRatings/modelyear/"+year+"/make/ACURA/model/"+model+"?format=csv"

import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    html = response.read()

with open(model+year+".csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(html)
```

you can add some more variables to your url. Then for reading you can use the pandas package.

```
import pandas as pd
vechiles = pd.read_csv("vichles.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..if I simply put the URL in my browser, it automatically downloads the csv file into my Downloads folder. Can this be done? Also, I am getting error 'No such file or directory' for your second to last line i.e. with open(model+year+".csv") as f..How will this file be created?